# only GPS location tracking

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, location

I'm working on a location based tracking app. Does anyone know how to use only gps location and not network provider location. Since i'm using acess_fine_location in my manifest it uses both. 
This is my tracking code:

```
package com.persasrl.paul.quickfit;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class StepCounter extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

// Request code to use when launching the resolution activity
private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 1001;
// Unique tag for the error dialog fragment
private static final String DIALOG_ERROR = "dialog_error";
// Bool to track whether the app is already resolving an error
private boolean mResolvingError = false;

//keys



GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
TextView mDistanceText;
TextView mTimeText;
Location mLastLocation;
Location mCurrentLocation;
UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
float[] d = new float[1];
float totald=0;
int type;


private MCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private long timeElapsed;

private final long startTime = 9223372036854775807L;
private final long interval = 1;

LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_step_counter);
    userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
    mDistanceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dist);
    mTimeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    mResolvingError = savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, false);
    Intent startIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = startIntent.getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null)
    type= bundle.getInt("sport");
    isGpsConnected();
    createLocationRequest();
    buildGoogleApiClient();

}

public void isGpsConnected()
{
    // Get Location Manager and check for GPS & Network location services
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        // Build the alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
        builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(!mResolvingError)
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

public void stopApp(View view)
{
    User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();
    Workout workout = new Workout (totald,type,user.username,timeElapsed);
    registerWorkout(workout);
}

private void registerWorkout(Workout workout) {
    ServerRequests serverRequest = new ServerRequests(this);
    serverRequest.storeWorkoutDataInBackground(workout, new GetWorkoutCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(Workout returnedWorkout) {
            Intent Intent = new Intent(StepCounter.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(Intent);
        }
    });
}

public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    countDownTimer = new MCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    countDownTimer.start();
    startLocationUpdates();
}

//pana aici merge de aici vine partea cu update

protected void startLocationUpdates() {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(500);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(mCurrentLocation!=null)
        mLastLocation = mCurrentLocation;
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    if(mLastLocation!=null && mCurrentLocation!=null)
        updateDistance();
}



public void updateDistance()
{
    Location.distanceBetween(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), d);
    if(!(d[0]<0.001))
    totald+=d[0];
    mDistanceText.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.3f", totald)));
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}



// De aici partea cu rezolvatu problemei


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    //todo nust...
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (mResolvingError) {
        // Already attempting to resolve an error.
        return;
    } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mResolvingError = true;
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        // Show dialog using GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog()
        showErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode());
        mResolvingError = true;
    }
}

// The rest of this code is all about building the error dialog

/* Creates a dialog for an error message */
private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
    // Create a fragment for the error dialog
    ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
    // Pass the error that should be displayed
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DIALOG_ERROR, errorCode);
    dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
    dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "errordialog");
}

/* Called from ErrorDialogFragment when the dialog is dismissed. */
public void onDialogDismissed() {
    mResolvingError = false;
}


/* A fragment to display an error dialog */
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public ErrorDialogFragment() { }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the error code and retrieve the appropriate dialog
        int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ERROR);
        return GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(
                this.getActivity(), errorCode, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ((StepCounter) getActivity()).onDialogDismissed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
        mResolvingError = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                    !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
private static final String STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR = "resolving_error";

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, mResolvingError);
}

//timer
public class MCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
{

    public MCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval)
    {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        mTimeText.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(startTime));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        long hours=0;
        long minutes=0;
        long seconds=0;
        timeElapsed = (startTime - millisUntilFinished)/1000;
        seconds= timeElapsed%60;
        minutes= timeElapsed/60%60;
        hours = timeElapsed/3600;
        mTimeText.setText(String.valueOf(hours) + ":" + String.valueOf(minutes)+ ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
    }
}


}
```

And my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    //android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StepCounter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_step_counter" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: What problems you are facing?

Comment: Well i would like to make an app to track my running progress, and when i have wi-fi open the app says that i make like 2 m per second just staying in place. If i have only gps on it works just fine. I would like to make the app only use gps even if wi-fi is on.